# Reloading constant generated with inherited with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance

I have a concern with realoding of constant in rails. More specifically, with a constant that is filled by an inherited [method](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Class.html#method-i-inherited) :

EDIT : This concerns is relative to development mode, not production.

Here is the code :

```
# helpers/my_active_code/formatter.rb
module MyActiveCode
  class Formatter
    FORMATTER_MAPPING = ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess.new # just a constant
    # Will store something like : 
    # { 
    #    "String" => ::MyActiveCode::Transforms::String,
    #    "Boolean" => ::MyActiveCode::Transforms::Boolean,
    # }
  end
end

# helpers/my_active_code/transforms/object.rb
module MyActiveCode::Transforms
  class Object
    # A superclass that implement an inherited method which store into the constant
    private
    def self.inherited(subclass)
      ActiveRecordViewRewrite::Formatter::FORMATTER_MAPPING.store(identifier, subclass)
    end
  end
end

# helpers/my_active_code/transforms/string.rb
module MyActiveCode::Transforms
  class String
  end
end
```

I also got an initializer that require all files into the folder helpers/my_active_code/transforms.

When i start the rails console, all work fine, the FORMATTER_MAPPING constant is well filled.

However, after a reload (reload!) the FORMATTER_MAPPING constant is empty ({}).

This is perfectly normal due to the constant-reloading describe here : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#constant-reloading

So i try to reload all my transforms file into (helpers/my_active_code/transforms) at the end of the file helpers/my_active_code/formatter.rb but it does not work.

How can I solve this and always get this constant filled?

Comment: Why are you defining a **constant**, and then **editing** it with data? This does not make sense.

Comment: Or to put it another way, shouldn't you be using an instance variable, with data set in the `initialize` method?

Comment: You mean that i have to use a singleton to store these data? Don't feel conformable with this. The purpose is near to simple_form wrapper. I don't know how they store their wrapper but i will give a look. Good idea.